# SharePoint 2013 filter search by specific permissions

Tags: search

Is it possible to filter search results to only return items that the current user has for instance "Write" permissions for?

I know the search crawl is permission aware in that only the items you have access to will be returned when searching, but is it possible to control this more finely?

Ideally I'd like to be able to only return results for which the current user has a given SharePoint permission (like edit items, view versions) or simply only return results the current user has Write access to.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without customization. On premises you could write a custom security trimmer that looks for the write permission after the query runs.